# Git issue Unsupported proxy syntax in '127.0.0.1:(proxy http port number)'

Tags: git

I want to clone the file from github but it reports such a problem.

---

Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Nikko-X/Daily-Training--C-and-C-.git/': Unsupported proxy syntax in '127.0.0.1:(proxy http port number)'

Comment: You need an actual number, such as `<addr>:1234` to use port 1234. The literal string `(proxy http port number)` isn't valid here.

Comment: Thank you very munch for your answer, It's already working.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your Git is configured to use an outbound proxy.

Check your Git outbound proxy configuration and unset it.

```
# Get global value
git config --global --get https.proxy
git config --global --get http.proxy

# Unset global value
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy may only use https.

In this case, replacing `http.proxy` by `https.proxy` in git config might fix the error:

"Unsupported proxy syntax in 'https:"